# Rexx error - ISPT024 Error on input/output

Tags: rexx, tso

can anyone please explain to me what does this error mean?

ISPSTART PGM(DSQQMFE) NEWAPPL PARM(F=999999,M=B,S=DSND, I=KMSDBA.PROMQMF (&&TYPE=QUERY &&DB2SRC=U123730 &&DB2OWNER=BCD75DBA &&INFO=D
EF-677946))
  ISPT024 Error on input/output   -/-Unexpected return code 5 from CDG/CDP. RC=13 implies disk full. 
READY 
END

Answer (score 4):

[The documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r13/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r13.f54mc00/ispzmc9003.htm) indicates this is an I/O problem with an ISPF table (not a DB2 table, I see you're trying to start QMF).

The user response is to contact your systems programmer - in this case that would be the person responsible for this ISPF dialog.  If that person is *you*, I suggest looking into the location of the applicable dataset in your [ISPTLIB](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r13/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r13.f54rs00/ispffiles.htm) concatenation and checking with your storage administrator on how much space is available on that volume.